# how to run the files within a folder using an executable file?

Tags: command-line, files, executable

I want to run some files within a directory (mike1). I have to use an executable file that is in another directory(Zacros). How can I do it?
The software's manual says:
"Zacros expects all the right input files to be in the current directory"

I have checked and all the files are in mike1/100

From the command prompt I have tried the following:

> ```
> cd Zacros
> cd build
> ./zacros.x
> ```

Result: 
WITH THREADS 2
STOP         1
It works!

The problem begins when I add the path to the folders I want the executable file to read.

```
  cd Zacros
```

> ```
> cd build
> ./zacros.x /mike1/100
> ```

Error: got mike1/100 which is not valid.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the executable file in the directory you were in before doing `cd mike1`? what is its name (`zacros`? `zacros.x`?)

Comment: Before cd mike1 I was in the command prompt. The executable "zacros.x" is in the "Zacros" directory.

Comment: @user3689783 that makes no sense. you are not showing a Zacros directory in your question.

Comment: This is wrong "Error: got mike1/100 which is not valid." "./zacros.x /mike1/100" would return  "Error: got /mike1/100 which is not valid." It would have the / in the error notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
mike1/100/./zacros.x
```

is invalid. The . goes at the FRONT of the command if you are at the directory where mike1 is in.

```
./mike1/100/zacros.x
```

When zacros.x is inside /100 and you are 1 dir lower you do

```
cd mike1/100
../zacros.x
```

If it is inside mike1 (so you are 2 dirs lower):

```
../../zacros.x
```

You can also do

```
../../mike1/100/zacros.x
```

if you are 2 directories deep and need to go into 2 other directories.

edit

```
cd build
./zacros.x /mike1/100
```

why do you put a / in front of mike1? The system will try to find it at the root of the filesystem. Please point to it relatively from the dir Zacros: use ../mike1/100 to go 1 up from Zacros or mike1/100 if you have mike1 in Zacros.

---

> Let me clarify, here is the executable: Zacros/build/zacros.x, the files are in the following directory: mike1/100/. If I type what you suggested: cd build ./zacros.x /mike/100, it says it is not valid.

If those are relative paths from the beginning:

```
cd Zacros/build/
./zavros.x ../../mike1/100/
```

could be what it need to be. But that is assuming those 2 are in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify, here is the executable: Zacros/build/zacros.x, the files are in the following directory: mike1/100/. If I type what you suggested: cd build  ./zacros.x /mike/100, it says it is not valid.

Comment: please add the result of 'tree' from the root of your project into the question

Answer (score 0):

First, cd to the directory you want to be in:

cd mike1

Then use the relative path, like this:

../build/zacros.x

Note, the ".." means one directory up from where you are.

Comment: Once in mike1 I typed what you suggested and  it displayed " no such file or directory". When I go to cd Zacros

Comment: what does the output look like if you type "ls -l " from your home dir?

Comment: There are some directories including "Zacros" (where the .x file is) and "mike1" (where the folder "100" is)